Essential Mac Feature Missing – AppleScript Question
I want to automatically convert the typed characters from one keyboard layout to the equivalent characters in another layout. I have two keyboard layouts (English and Farsi), and sometimes I mistakenly type with the wrong one and need to correct it. I was wondering if there is an AppleScript available to perform this task with a keyboard shortcut.
Currently, the code below partially achieves this by converting English characters in the clipboard to Farsi characters. However, what I need is a script that can convert the selected characters to the other keyboard in real-time by pressing a shortcut, such as fn+F1.
-- Define the mappings between characters in the US English layout and the Persian Standard layout

set characterMappings to {{source:"q", target:"ض"}, {source:"w", target:"ص"}, {source:"e", target:"ث"}, {source:"r", target:"ق"}, {source:"t", target:"ف"}, {source:"y", target:"غ"}, {source:"u", target:"ع"}, {source:"i", target:"ه"}, {source:"o", target:"خ"}, {source:"p", target:"ح"}, {source:"a", target:"ش"}, {source:"s", target:"س"}, {source:"d", target:"ی"}, {source:"f", target:"ب"}, {source:"g", target:"ل"}, {source:"h", target:"ا"}, {source:"j", target:"ت"}, {source:"k", target:"ن"}, {source:"l", target:"م"}, {source:"z", target:"ظ"}, {source:"x", target:"ط"}, {source:"c", target:"ز"}, {source:"v", target:"ر"}, {source:"b", target:"ذ"}, {source:"n", target:"د"}, {source:"m", target:"پ"}}

-- Function to convert characters

on convertText(inputText, mappings)

set outputText to inputText

repeat with mapping in mappings

set sourceCharacter to source of mapping

set targetCharacter to target of mapping

set outputText to replaceText(outputText, sourceCharacter, targetCharacter)

end repeat

return outputText

end convertText

-- Function to replace text

on replaceText(inputText, searchString, replacementString)

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to searchString

set textItems to text items of inputText

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to replacementString

set newText to textItems as string

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""

return newText

end replaceText

-- Get the current clipboard content

set clipboardText to the clipboard as text

-- Convert the clipboard content

set convertedText to convertText(clipboardText, characterMappings)

-- Set the converted text to the clipboard

set the clipboard to convertedText

